# How to calculate average of Top 6 subjects in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports

I have a Table as  follow

```
ID Num  Subject                           Q01
012488  FILIPINO                           88
012488  ARALING PANLIPUNAN                 84
012488  EDUK. SA PAGPAPAHALAGA             84
012488  ENGLISH                            90
012488  SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY             92
012488  MATHEMATICS                        84
012488  MAPEH                              94
012488  MUSIC/ARTS/HEALTH                  94
012488  PHYSICAL EDUCATION                 94
012488  TECHNOLOGY & LIVELIHOOD EDUC.      96
```

I can get the **general average** by doing `Average ({Table.Q01})` in the formula fields. 
What I also want is getting the **academic average** which is the average of these list of subjects

```
FILIPINO, 
ARALING PANLIPUNAN, 
EDUK. SA PAGPAPAHALAGA, 
ENGLISH, 
SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY, 
MATHEMATICS
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem possible to reduce the size of your table directly with the Average function, maybe you should try using the [FILTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dax/filter-function-dax) from DAX Functions and sorting the values ​​you want to keep before averaging.

Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dax/filter-functions-dax) for more DAX infos

Comment: I am trying to store the values in an array using while loop, as an alternative.` x[i] := {Table.Q01}[i];` shows an error that a string or an array is required. How should I "convert" a column from a report field into an array?